# Sort an array of custom sub-objects in a one-to-many relationship by newest first

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to sort an array so that the newest ones are at the top.

The problem I have is that I'm sorting on a One to many relationship and using compare doesn't seem to sort it.

The array is a list of completed flights.

```
NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:[self entityName]];
    fr.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(acceptedDate != nil || booked == %@ || ANY legs.flight != nil) && ANY legs.departureDate <= %@", @YES, [NSDate date]];

    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil];

    //Check BOTH legs have completed        
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSMutableArray *filtered = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (Quote *quote in results) {
        if ([quote.legs count] > 1) {
            BOOL completed = YES;
            for (QuoteLeg *leg in quote.legs) {
                if ([leg.departureDate compare:now] == NSOrderedDescending) {
                    completed = NO;
                }
            }                
            if (completed) {
                [filtered addObject:quote];
            }
        }
        else {
            [filtered addObject:quote];
        }
    }

    // Try to sort the array
    [filtered sortedArrayWithOptions:NSSortStable usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Quote *quote1, Quote *quote2){
       QuoteLeg *leg1 = [[quote1.legs allObjects] firstObject];
       QuoteLeg *leg2 = [[quote2.legs allObjects] firstObject];

       return [leg1.departureDate compare:leg2.departureDate];
    }];

    // Sort filtered by date
    for (Quote *q in filtered) {
        QuoteLeg *leg = [[q.legs allObjects] firstObject];
        NSLog(@"date = %@", leg.departureDate);
    }
```

This always outputs

```
date = 2015-01-20 11:00:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-23 12:00:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-29 12:00:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-30 10:40:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-30 10:40:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-29 09:00:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-26 10:00:00 +0000
```

I'm needing to ensure that the dates are newest first.

Is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayWithOptions:(NSSortOptions)opts usingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

methods return the results as an `NSArray`, it does not sort your `NSMutableArray` in place. Try doing this instead

```
filtered = [filtered sortedArrayWithOptions:NSSortStable usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Quote *quote1, Quote *quote2){
       QuoteLeg *leg1 = [[quote1.legs allObjects] firstObject];
       QuoteLeg *leg2 = [[quote2.legs allObjects] firstObject];

        return [leg1.departureDate compare:leg2.departureDate];
            }];
```

Comment: This helps, but my dates are still unfortuently date earliest first = 2015-01-20 11:00:00 +0000, date = 2015-01-23 12:00:00 +0000, date = 2015-01-28 11:00:00 +0000, date = 2015-01-29 12:00:00 +0000   -- I'm wondering if I can force it to be newest date's first

Comment: @AtillaJax then why not return [leg2.departureDate compare:leg1.departureDate]. (Or reverse the resulting array)

Comment: I tried reversing the array, the problem is that the items in the array are custom classes, not like strings or whatever.  Also, there is no guarantee that the order will be correct when I reverse it.  I'll try your idea of leg2 vs leg1 instead of leg1 vs leg2

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer.  I tried wrapping a `NSSortDescriptor` around it without any key and the results seem to be in the order I require;

```
        // Filtered is a NSMutableArray
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:NO
                                                                      comparator:^NSComparisonResult(VICQuote *quote1, VICQuote *quote2){
                                                                          VICQuoteLeg *leg1 = [[quote1.legs allObjects] firstObject];
                                                                          VICQuoteLeg *leg2 = [[quote2.legs allObjects] firstObject];

                                                                        return [leg1.departureDate compare:leg2.departureDate];
                                                                      }];
        [filtered sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

        NSArray *finalResults = [NSArray arrayWithArray:filtered];

        // Output them
        for (VICQuote *q in finalResults) {
            VICQuoteLeg *leg = [[q.legs allObjects] firstObject];
            NSLog(@"date = %@", leg.departureDate);
        }
```

Results:

```
date = 2015-01-31 10:35:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-30 09:40:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-29 12:00:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-29 09:00:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-28 11:00:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-23 12:00:00 +0000
date = 2015-01-20 11:00:00 +0000
```